# Checking two conditions before compiling using Ant build

Tags: ant

I want to check for presence of dependent files before my code is compiled. I am doing the following

```
<available file="XX" property="isXXAvailable"/>
<available file="YY" property="isYYAvailable"/>
```

For compilation I want to check whether both the properties are true. Only then go ahead with the compilation

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" unless="isXXAvailable" unless="isYYavailable">
```

Is it possible to check for both the properties during compiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'AND' two 'available' condtions together into a single one :

```
<condition property="files.available">
  <and>
    <available file="XX"/>
    <available file="YY"/>
  </and>
</condition>
```

then you can use this condition in the same way you are currently doing in your target

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html